# scaling in android buttons and textview misplaced

Tags: android

Iam new to Android pleasse helo me on this.How can I scale my app for different screens I am using, unit in dp, Linear and Relative layout, Layout folders small,normal, large when I open small layout the layout gets scaled to  small but the buttons still stays the same size which ie. button and textview size not changing according to the screen size. please help on this

Answer (score 0):

u have to use different button in layout small, try to use smallButton in `layout-small`, or you can give hard coded values to `Button` and its text.